# mysqli_connect v/s number of mysql connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a php page index.php in my local machine.

Following is the code

```
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","********","**");

sleep(25);
echo "yes";
```

I opened a mysql prompt in my linux terminal ( ie...  mysql -u root -p)

And it shows

```
Threads_connected | 1
```

Now i taking the index.php in one browser (Firefox)

Now

```
Threads_connected | 2
```

Then i takes the same page in four tabs of the same browser(Firefox), before completing the previous execution of same page,(so 5 instance of same page is running)

Now

Threads_connected | 2

***Why? should it 6?***

If i take the php page in another browser(say chrome), before completing the previous execution of same page,

Now

```
Threads_connected | 3
```

Why?

So how is mysqli_connect  depends the number of mysql connections.?

I thought if we use mysqli_connect  and each time the page executes , a new mysql connection will create and it will automatically close once the script execution complete .

And if we use mysqli_pconnect, then it will reuse any existing connection thread.

So what is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Have you considered, that the browser may be caching your result page and thus no new request arrives at the webserver (PHP script)?

Comment: Sirko,Thanks for your response.So you saying , there will be a new mysql connection is happening , while taking the page in each time?And here its not happening  because of cache?

Comment: @Amal Thanks for your response.But i didn't get it clearly.Can u explain it little more?

Comment: At least this would be a consistent reason for your observed behavior. Each browser seems to open just one connection to the database. To validate, you could add some varying parameter to the calls inside one browser. They should not be cached and thus result in multiple connections.

Comment: @Sirko, i just executed the page in one tab.Then before completing the execution of that page ,i edited the code and added a line like  echo "123"; .Then took the same page in some more tabs of same browser.But still there is no increase in the connection string ,except 1 connection of initial execution

Comment: To avoid caching, just use an URL like this: `yourscript.php?nocach=123` and use different numbers for each tab. If you still have just one connection afterwards, there is a different reason.

Comment: @Sirko, now its work as you said.there  will be new connections for each new tab.Let me know if i was using mysql_pconnect, then how many tabs  can connect in one connection string?

Comment: There should be one permanent connection per tab as the other tabs have not returned their connection to the pool. You should however use [`mysqli_connect` with the `p:` flag for host](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#refsect1-mysqli.construct-parameters).

Comment: @Sirko.Its not clearly understand.If i opened 4 tabs with mysqli_connect with the p: flag.Then there will be only one connection, right?And let  me know, how many tabs can use this  connection string?

Comment: Persistent connections are *not* shared between concurrent running scripts. One script has to be finished, before the connection is released (or you release it manually) and can be reused by another script. So if you open 4 tabs simultaneously, there will be 4 connections.

Comment: @Sirko,Thanks for your explanations.If you put your opinion as a answer, i can give the right answer to it.I simultaneously executed the index.php  with different query string in  4 tabs with mysql_pconnect.And i checked the variable Threads_connected  and it show only 1.Why?